# In Excel, how do you autofill intermittent rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to autofill data from other sheet in a intermittent way. Example:

```
        A (every 2)
1 ='Sheet1'!A2
2 ='Sheet1'!A4
3 ='Sheet1'!A6
4 ='Sheet1'!A8
5 ='Sheet1'!A10
```

or

```
        A (every 3)
1 ='Sheet1'!A3
2 ='Sheet1'!A6
3 ='Sheet1'!A9
4 ='Sheet1'!A12
5 ='Sheet1'!A15
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind to pull down manually to get the data?

Here is a sample in Sheet1.

[image]

To get the data of row with multiple of 2, please try the formula "=IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(2*ROW(A1)-1),,)=0,"",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(2*ROW(A1)-1),,))" and pull down.

To get the data of row with multiple of 3, please try the formula "=IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(3*ROW(A1)-1),,)=0,"",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(3*ROW(A1)-1),,))", pull down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW multiplied by your factor.

So for each 2 use:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&ROW()*2)
```

For each 3 use:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&ROW()*3)
```

And so on....